# ubuntu core - kiosk mode with web browser

Tags: ubuntu-core, kiosk

Can anyone confirm me if it is possible to boot ubuntu core into a full screen web browser at the moment (aka kiosk mode) ?
I've found this [project](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/guides/mir-snaps/), but it seems more focused in Qt applications. The mir-server is there, but how to deploy a browser (like firefox, chrome) with this setup?
The snap system is still new to me, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snap-based solution using 2 snaps:

- First, install `mir-kiosk`:

  ```
  sudo snap install mir-kiosk
  ```
- Then, install `chromium-mir-kiosk`. Please note to add the `devmode` flag, otherwise, the screen will remain black:

  ```
  sudo snap install chromium-mir-kiosk --beta --devmode
  ```
- Finally, daemonize `mir-kiosk` to start after boot:

  ```
  sudo snap set mir-kiosk daemon=true
  ```

To customize the startup URL for chromium use:

```
 sudo snap set chromium-mir-kiosk url="https://yoururl.com"
```

This answer was adapted from the topic ["Install mir-kiosk and chromium-mir-kiosk under Ubuntu 18.04 Server](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/install-mir-kiosk-and-chromium-mir-kiosk-under-ubuntu-18-04-server/13108%22) on Ubuntu Community Discourse.  The source pertains to Ubuntu server, but should also work on Ubuntu Core since it is snap-based.

Comment: chromium-mir-kiosk is no longer maintained